# Proof of Schwarz inequality

Tags: inequality

Schwarz inequality can be proved by using vector addition property and pythagoras theorem. Is there any other way of proving it?

Comment: There's one using induction too! :D

Answer (score 4):

There are many [pro](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=different%20proofs%20of%20schwarz%20inequality)[ofs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=different%20proofs%20of%20cauchy-schwarz) of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, here's one of them: Consider the following quadratic polynomial: $$f(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2  \right)x^2-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i  \right)x+\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_ix-b_i)^2.  $$ Since $f(x)\geqslant0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, it follows that the discriminant of $f(x)$ is negative, i.e., $$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2\right)\leqslant0
$$
Therefore: $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2\right)\geqslant\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)^2.$$

Comment: Hakim's link was very useful, http://rgmia.org/papers/v12e/Cauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice one. Recall that an inner product for real vectors has the following properties:

$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$

$\langle ax+y,z\rangle=a\langle x,z\rangle+\langle y,z\rangle$

$\langle x,x\rangle\geq0$

Then 
$0\leq\langle lx+y,lx+y\rangle=l^2\langle x,x\rangle+l\langle x,y\rangle+l\langle y,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle=l^2\langle x,x\rangle+2l\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle$

This is a quadratic equation in $l$ with at most 1 real root. Therefore

$b^2-4ac\leq 0$

$\implies4{\langle x,y\rangle}^2-4\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle\leq 0$

$\implies{\langle x,y\rangle}^2\leq\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle$

Not bad huh? Sadly the proof for complex vectors isn't quite as elagent, though can still be fairly simple.